# how to recursively go over a list

Tags: python

```
def remove_allr(x,xlst,xtmp = []):
     if xlst[0] == x:
         return remove_allr(x,xlst)
     else:
         xtmp.append(xlst)
         return remove_allr(x,xlst)
     return xtmp
```

I'm trying to figure out how to iterate over the list and look for `x` which in this case is 1 and remove all of the instances of `x` from `xlst` which in this case is `[1,1,2,1,2]`. It should be outputting `[2,2]` but it only gives me an empty list. It must be done recursively as I am trying to figure this out to better my understanding of recursion.

Comment: `list(filter(lambda x: x != 1, my_list))`

Comment: Is using recursion a requirement, because it’s very easy without and probably much harder and more expensive to do it using recursion.

Comment: If it wasn't recursively I wouldn't be here lol

Comment: If the first element is x then the result is just the result of using the function with the rest of the list. If the first element is not x then the result is the first element concatenated with the result of using the function with the rest of the list. You have got that idea right. Hints: you shouldn’t use a static xtmp list, you should return two different things in the two cases, and you need a base case to end the recursion.

Comment: Edit your _requirement_ for recursion into your question, and also explain if this is an assignment/homework.

Comment: no, I am just trying to better understand recursion

Comment: I think you have chosen the wrong task. This is much easier to do with a normal loop or list comprehension. There are better examples / exercises to understand recursion.

Comment: Factorial is something good to practice recursion, the most basic.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your recursion is endless and never ending. Please be careful when dealing with recursive functions.

```
def remove_allr(x, xlst):
   if xlst:
       if xlst[0] == x:
           return remove_allr(x, xlst[1:])
       return [xlst[0]] + remove_allr(x, xlst[1:])
   return []


input_list = [1, 1, 2, 1, 2]
print(remove_allr(1, input_list)) # [2, 2]
```

It gives expected output.

Comment: If it helped you, accept the answer instead of voting. In this way, you will be guiding those who have this problem.
@kankykillimanjarooo

Answer (score 1):

First let me point out that using a mutable default argument is dangerous if you don't understand the ramifications of how it works:

```
def remove_elem(xl, x, res=[]): # don't do this!
```

do this:

```
def remote_elem(x1, x, res=None):
    if res is None:
        res = []
```

Appending to a mutable default argument **changes the default**. Instead, use `None`, and create the initial mutable object if the default is `None`.  Note `is` is appropriate here because `None` (as well as `True` and `False`) are singletons.

For your recursion to work, recursion needs a termination condition and a recursive definition.  In this case it is:

- Termination condition: An empty list returns an empty list.
- Recursive definition:
  a. If first element is a match, return recursive call with list less first element.
  b. If first element doesn't match, return element + recursive call with list less first element.

Example (note the default argument wasn't needed):

```
def remove_allr(x,xlst):
    # termination condition
    if not xlst:
         return []

    # recursion
    if xlst[0] == x:
        return remove_allr(x,xlst[1:])
    else:
        return xlst[:1] + remove_allr(x,xlst[1:])

print(remove_allr(2,[1,2,3,2,4]))
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 4]
```

Here's a less repetitive, compact version:

```
def remove_allr(x,xlst):
    if not xlst:
        return []
    return ([] if xlst[0] == x else xlst[:1]) + remove_allr(x,xlst[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the better task to learn recursion, but here it is:

```
def remove_elem(xl, x, res=[]):
    if xl[0] != x:
        res.append(xl[0])
    if len(xl) > 1:
        return remove_elem(xl[1:], x, res)
    else:
        return res


example_list = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]
final_result = remove_elem(example_list, 1)  # final_result is [2, 2]
```

I think is not the better example because the recursive function needs an additional list to be passed during recursion to store the final result.

Each recursion the first element of the list is evaluated ad added to the result list if the condition is satisfied. Then if the list is longer that 1 (that is, there are other elements to be evaulated) the function is called recursively passing the rest of the list until all elements are evaluated.
The final `else` is where the recursion breaks and the final result is returned.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this?

```py
def remove_allr(x, oldlist):
    newlist = []
    for n in oldlist:
        if n != 1: newlist.append(n)

    return newlist

remove_allr(1, [1,1,2,1,2])
# [2, 2]
```

Recursively

```py
def remove_allr_rec(x, oldlist, newlist):
    if len(oldlist) == 0:
        return newlist

    last = oldlist.pop()

    if last != x:
        newlist.append(last)

    return remove_allr_rec(x, oldlist, newlist)

remove_allr_rec(1, [1, 1, 2, 1, 2], [])
# [2, 2]
```

Comment: Where's the recursion?

Comment: i don't think this is recursion its just a simple for loop which is way easier to do than recursively